# Effective mass of a particle

Tags: mass, semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory

I was reading about concept of [effective mass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_mass_%28solid-state_physics%29) on Wikipedia and came across the line that effective mass of a particle can be negative and even zero. How is this possible?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/104572/

Comment: It can also be anisotropic (for example in Silicon)