# Why is the effective mass of top band just $-1$ times that of the bottom band?

Tags: condensed-matter, mass, electronic-band-theory, tight-binding

In band theory, the formula for effective mass is $$m^* = \frac{\hbar^2}{\frac{d^2E}{dk^2}}$$ and $m_{top}^* = -1 \times m_{bottom}^*$ the effective mass of top band is just -1 times the bottom band. What is the significance/proof of this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Physical significance of electrons with negative effective mass. Are they holes or what?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/558915/)

Comment: In one case you diffirentiate near the maximum, in the other near the minimum of the band.